# How to call async function within non async function in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, coroutine

I know about **await** and **async** must be pair. But. here is my problem:

I hava a function like

```py
def url_open(req):
    #fetch url content synchronize
```

and now, I want to change to another version like:

```py
def url_open(req):
    await self.websocket.send(req)
    content = await self.websocket.recv()
```

the problem is `url_open` function was exist in many place in the whole project, and it 'is in the bottom of the call tree.  it's not possible to make all the caller to be async function.

So, how can I make this work? get some result from another **async** functions like in  python `websocket` module?

======= **updated** ======

After I tried as @Viliam Popovec provided
I got this **warning**

```py
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'hello' was never awaited
```

and **error**

```py
This event loop is already running
```

The websocket was run like this in my app

```py
async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(echo, '0.0.0.0', 8001):
        await asyncio.Future()

asyncio.run(main())
```

It't seems that the new **event loop** has conflicts with the existing **websocket runloop**

Comment: The error points to a function / coroutine called `hello`. Most likely somewhere in code you are calling `hello()` instead of `await hello()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify all instances of `url_open` function to be ansynchronous, then you could use `loop`s to call some async function (*e.g. `hello(`) in code sample below*).

```
async def hello():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("Hello World!")


def url_open():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(hello())
```

Comment: This is correct, but it should be noted that calling individual async functions this way does NOT provide the usual advantages of real asynchronous programs. The sync function `run_until_complete` will block until completion.

Comment: Yes that's true. The only way utilize the advantages of asynchronous programs would be to rewrite all instances of the function to be asynchronous and then call them asynchronously. However OP asked how to get a result from `async` function inside a synchronous one, this answer satisfies it

Comment: @ViliamPopovec I have update the question when I tried your solution. Could you give me a help. I'm sorry I was new to python.

Comment: Try using [nest_asyncio](https://pypi.org/project/nest-asyncio/) library. Alternatively share a sample of your code reproducing the Error. When calling `async` function either use `await` keyword (inside another async function) or make sure to call it via `loop.run_until_complete`

Comment: The whole project's entry was the main function above. It seems there has a conflict with existing event loop?

Comment: Can you share minimal reproducible example for me to check? You can send it via [codefile](https://codefile.io/f/zkfhPZKd2uL6wejMdrDV) for example